# Need to boot hourly workspaces but start_workspaces() and describe_workspaces() limited to 25

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-workspaces

I have the below script that works on booting workspaces, but it gets the first 25 Workspaces, despite being AVAILABLE or STOPPED state.

I am running more than 25 Workspaces in my environment and I am trying to figure out what is there I need to add on it, in order to check all workspaces in my environment (50<) and initiate START to the ones that are in a STOPPED state.

I look forward hearing your feedback.

Thanks

```html
import boto3

workspaces = boto3.client('workspaces')


def lambda_handler(event, context):

  workspaces_client_list = workspaces.describe_workspaces()

  for workspaces_info in workspaces_client_list['Workspaces']:
    workspace_id = workspaces_info['WorkspaceId']
    workspace_state = workspaces_info['State']

    if workspace_state == 'STOPPED':
      start_workspaces(workspace_id)


def start_workspaces(workspace_id):

  workspaces.start_workspaces(
    StartWorkspaceRequests = [
      {
        'WorkspaceId': workspace_id
      },
    ]
  )
```

Comment: what is the timeout of your lambda function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation states](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/api/API_DescribeWorkspaces.html) that you can provide a `Limit` in the request parameters

> **Limit**
>
> The maximum number of items to return.
> Type: Integer
> Valid Range: Minimum value of 1. Maximum value of 25.
> Required: No

You only get 25 items because it's the maximum number of items you can get. To get all items you have to check in any response whether there [`NextToken`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/workspaces.html#WorkSpaces.Client.describe_workspaces). If there is a next token you have to use it for the next request, you iterate this until there is no next token left.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
   workspaces_client_list = get_all_workspaces()

   for workspaces_info in workspaces_client_list:
     workspace_id = workspaces_info['WorkspaceId']
     workspace_state = workspaces_info['State']

     if workspace_state == 'STOPPED':
       start_workspaces(workspace_id)

def get_all_workspaces():
   response = workspaces.describe_workspaces()
   workspaces_client_list = response['Workspaces']
   while "NextToken" in response:
    response = workspaces.describe_workspaces(NextToken=response['NextToken'])
    workspaces_client_list.extend(response['Workspaces'])    
    
   return workspaces_client_list
```

Comment: Thank you @st.huber it is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Awesome. Feel free to upvotate and mark this answer as the accepted answer, which will make it easier for others to find it as well